# How to send a file with RTK Query from Redux Toolkit?

Tags: redux, file-upload, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I am trying to use RTK Query mutations to upload a file to the API. Here is my mutation code:

```
    addBanner: builder.mutation({
          query(body) {
            return {
              url: `/api/banners`,
              method: 'POST',
              body,
            }
          },
        })
```

Here is how I generate the data for request.

```
    const [addBanner, { isBannerLoading }] = useAddBannerMutation();
```

```
    const new_banner = new FormData();    
    new_banner.append("file", my_file);
    new_banner.append("type", my_type);
    new_banner.append("title", my_title);
    addBanner(new_banner).unwrap().then( () => ...
```

But I get an error:

```
A non-serializable value was detected in the state, in the path: `api.mutations.L-Mje7bYDfyNCC4NcxFD3.originalArgs.file`...
```

I know I can disable non-serializable check entirely through middleware, but I don't think it is an appropriate way of using Redux Toolkit and RTK. Without a file all works fine. Is there any **right** way of uploading files with RTK?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit: This has been fixed with @reduxjs/toolkit 1.6.1 - please update your package

---

I just opened an issue for this: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/1239 - thanks for bringing it up!

For now, you'll probably have to disable that check (you can do so for a certain path in the state while keeping it for the rest with the [ignoredPath](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/serializabilityMiddleware#options) option).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I will use ignoredPath for now, but I hope we'll have a solution by the time we go production.

Comment: This has been fixed with @reduxjs/toolkit 1.6.1 - please update your package

Answer (score 0):

pass `formData` in the query.

Like this:

```
 addBanner: builder.mutation({
          query(body) {
            return {
              url: `/api/banners`,
              method: 'POST',
              body,
              formData: true,
            }
          },
        })
```